# Split line from the end (cross-platform)

Tags: bash, replace

I have text that needs to be split; namely, put space after two characters from the end of the line. From "*4.20GB*" you need to get "*4.20 GB*". I know it can be done with `sed`, `awk`, etc., but I am looking for a light and more cross-platform method (for Linux/Unix/BSD).

Is it possible to do it with `bash` and its functions? For some reason, I thought `printf` could do it, but a quick check didn't yield anything positive.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for "more cross-platform method than `sed`" and then asking "Is it possible to do it with `bash` and its functions?"

It's safe bet to say that `sed` is installed (or "easily installable") on more computer architectures than `bash` so using `sed` should be more "cross-platform" than using `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, each line that finishes with some digits followed by GB, needs you to add a space before GB. I shouldn't use the word *split* that suggests you want to split one line into two lines.

Try:

```sh
sed -i 's/GB$/ GB/' [filenames ...]
```

I think that `sed` is more "cross-platform" than `bash`, because wherever you have `bash`, you easily will have `sed`, as @fuxoft says in his answer.